# Not able to read file after writing in python using subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess

```
import subprocess

with open('disk.txt','w') as fr:
        subprocess.Popen(['df','-h'],stdout=fr)

with open('disk.txt','r') as fp:
        header=fp.readline()
        for line in fp:
                val=line.split()[-2][:-1]
                print(val)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`subprocess.Popen()` starts a process and returns you an object you can use to check its status; it *doesn't* wait for that process to complete, so there's no reason to expect the writes to be finished before your code runs its reads.

One option is to use `subprocess.call()` instead of `subprocess.Popen()`, so your code waits for the process to complete before proceeding:

```
with open('disk.txt','w') as fr:
    subprocess.call(['df','-h'], stdout=fr)
```

Another is to make the delay explicit:

```
with open('disk.txt','w') as fr:
    p = subprocess.Popen(['df','-h'], stdout=fr)
    p.wait()
```

And of course, you can avoid the whole issue by iterating directly over the output as it's streamed rather than writing to a file at all:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(['df', '-h'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
header = p.stdout.readline()
for line in p.stdout:
    val = line.rsplit(None, 2)[-2].rstrip('%')
    print val
```

Comment: Thanks @Charles Duffy .. Got that right. Worked perfectly fine now .